# What does "to wear the leather on one's boots through" mean?

Tags: meaning

Please explain what **"to wear the leather on one's boots through"** means. I cannot imagine how that act is.

The context:
"I won't let you dance until you wear the leather on your boots through."

Thank you

Comment: If something is *worn through* it is worn to the point that there is a hole in it.

Comment: It could mean "to break in the boots," that is, "to soften the leather". In this case, "wear" means to  "grind down" or "erode". But I don't understand the context at all or the use of "through". With the use of "through" it seems like an idiom meaning "to wear ones boots until they have a hole in them." But that doesn't work in the context... Are you sure the context doesn't say "I won't let you STOP dancing until..."?

Comment: Thank you Jim and Silenus for your explanations. I'm sure the context says "I won't let you dance...", before that the girl had said to the boy: "No dancing, that's one of the rules." But I still feel confused about the meaning of this sentence. If he doesn't let her dance how can she wear the leather on her boots through (which means her boots will have a hole in them).

Comment: I wonder If he would like to describe the idea that: "We just dance a little, I won't let you dance so much (that your boots have a hole in them)". If not, how should he say to describe that idea? Could you please give me an example for that?

Answer (score 1):

Context is everything in something like this. He asks her to dance. She doesn't want to. He pulls her to the dance floor anyway, promising not to force her to dance until her boot leather is worn through; he won't even force her dance all night.

It's hyperbole. Of course he won't do that. She doesn't want to dance at all. Yet she dances happily until she collapses.

I only read the part of the one page, but what I did read isn't terribly well written.

Comment: Thank you so much Medica for your explanation as well as for your guidance on how to give a context!

Comment: It's an interesting phrase. Without the OP's clarification of context, it could also be interpreted as coming from a dance instructor who won't let a student perform until they've rehearsed a whole lot more.

Comment: @Lawrence: Yeah, I see. By the way, please let me know what OP in the phrase of "OP's clarification of context" is.

Comment: @anongoodnurse (Medica): I am not quite sure what "isn't terribly well written" means. Please help me to get the idea.

Comment: @Lawrence: So, the meaning of the phrase when it is in the context I gave is almost opposite to the one that you gave, isn't it? The one I gave is that the boy let her dance (but not much) and the one you gave is that the boy won't let her dance (unless she would have practiced much more)

Comment: @Nhu_Doan OP means Original Poster here, that is, the one who posted the question (i.e.for this question, you :) ).

Comment: @Nhu_Doan [Ref](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/85168/what-does-to-wear-the-leather-on-ones-boots-through-mean/85169?noredirect=1#comment164810_85169) Yes, that's what I thought was particularly interesting there - it could almost be its own opposite. This arises from what the word *won't* refers to: dancing at all, or the amount of dancing; and what *until* refers back to: how long permission is withheld, or the duration of the dance.